# Unable to access record even if table has records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 schemas on my DB i.e. Host and Staging.
I have given SELECT grant on table host.ctrl_test to user staging.
But when I fire select query on host.ctrl_test table from staging user, it returns 0 rows.

```
SQL> conn host

Enter password:

Connected.

SQL> select count(1) from host.ctrl_test;

  COUNT(1)
----------
     14455

SQL> conn staging

Enter password:

Connected.

SQL> select count(1) from host.ctrl_test;

  COUNT(1)
----------
         0
```

Comment: Do you perhaps have something like [a VPD policy](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/vpd.htm#DBSEG007) on the table?

Comment: Is `host.ctrl_test` a VIEW (instead of a table) which depends on current user name?

Comment: host.ctrl_test  is table in host schema

Comment: have you committed your transactions?

Comment: Yes mate.... Records in ctrl_param table are already committed.

Comment: Do both schemas use the same explain plan?  Maybe one of them has a session setting that is preventing an index from working, and the index is corrupt and needs to be built.  (That's a one-in-a-million problem, don't always rebuild your indexes.)

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons for this behavior include:

1. **Forgot to commit or using wrong database** 99.999% of these problems are caused by forgetting to commit, or unintentionally looking at the wrong database.  To avoid the inevitable "did you commit?" question, it helps to post fully-reproducible test cases in a simple text-based environment like SQL*Plus, with a prompt that shows the user and database name.
2. **Temporary table** For global temporary tables or private temporary tables the data will only be visible to one session.
3. **Virtual Private Database/Translation/Advanced Rewrite** Oracle has a few features where you can silently replace a query with another query, depending on the user.  Normally you can see these weird changes going on in an execution plan, in the Note section.
4. **View that depends on session setting** The table is really a view, and contains conditions that depend on session settings.
5. **Wrong-results bug/Corruption** About one in a trillion times there may be a corrupt index that is giving wrong results, but only for certain sessions that happen to use the index.